# returning URL instead of image - pulling data from XML using PHP regular expression

Tags: php, xml, regex, rss

I have this function called get_current_weather_data() which basically gets weather from a Yahoo XML feed.  I can return all the values I like such as, location, temperature and current condition, however; I'm having trouble getting the image associated with the current conditions.

This is the area I'm trying to get pull in the image:

```
// get weather icon url 
$description = $xml->channel->item->description;

//preg match regular expression to extract weather icon
$imgpattern = '/src="(.*?)"/i';
preg_match($imgpattern, $description, $matches);

$weather['icon_url'] = $matches[1];
echo $weather['icon_url'];
```

What is returned from the above code is simply the image URL, not the image.  Any idea?

The feed URL:

```
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=USNY0996&u=f
```

or if you prefer, a snippet from the above URL that I'm pulling in: (Notice the img src I'm currently pulling in)

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/34.gif"/><br /> <b>Current Conditions:</b><br     /> Fair, 40 F<BR /> <BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR /> Tue - Sunny. High: 44 Low: 32<br /> Wed -     Partly Cloudy. High: 47 Low: 39<br /> <br /> <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/New_York__NY/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USNY0996_f.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/> (provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
```

]]>

get_current_weather_data() function:

```
function get_current_weather_data() {

// Get XML data from source
$feed = file_get_contents("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=USNY0996&u=f");

// Check to ensure the feed exists
if (!$feed) {
    die('Weather not found! Check feed URL');
}

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

$weather['city'] = $xml->channel->children('yweather', TRUE)->location->attributes()->city;
echo $weather['city'] . "<br />";

$weather['temp'] = $xml->channel->item->children('yweather', TRUE)->condition->attributes()->temp;
echo $weather['temp'] . "<br />";

$weather['conditions'] = $xml->channel->item->children('yweather', TRUE)->condition->attributes()->text;
echo $weather['conditions'] . "<br />";

// get weather icon url 
$description = $xml->channel->item->description;

//preg match regular expression to extract weather icon
$imgpattern = '/src="(.*?)"/i';
preg_match($imgpattern, $description, $matches);

$weather['icon_url'] = $matches[1];
echo $weather['icon_url'];

return $weather;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the actual image data, you could use

```
file_get_contents($weather['icon_url']);
```

Comment: icon_url should be an image not a string.

Comment: $weather['icon_url'] is the image url parsed from the xml. file_get_contents will look up the url and get the binary image data. is that what you want?

Comment: @ thatwasbrilliant  I'm trying to parse back the actual image itself.  I would like the .gif image to be displayed

Comment: Displayed where? If you want to display it in the browser alongside the other text data, just put the url in an HTML IMG tag. You don't need the actual image data for that.

Comment: @ thatwasbrilliant The url for the image is updated according to the weather. For example, if it is sunny, image1.gif will be displayed and on a wet day, image2.gif will be displayed.  I'm pulling the image from a XML that is updating continuously.

Comment: echo '<img src='.$weather['icon_url'].' />';